# add new column to existing table with auto_increment constrain

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to add custId to an existing table Cust in which all the other fields are filled with data. I've used the following but i keep getting an error.

```
ALTER TABLE cust ADD custId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

got the following error massage: 
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this

```
alter table cust add column custid integer primary key not null auto_increment;
```

This will

- Add column `custid` as primary key which will be auto incremented further.
- Populate `custid` starting with `1` in already existing data in `cust` table.

See the demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eda52a/1).

**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eda52a/1**

Comment: it works when i use this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eda52a/1 but it doesn't when i use the oracle i downloaded. 3.1.07 could that be the problem?

Comment: because it is displaying this error again:  "%s: invalid identifier"

Answer (score 1):

Use the right order:

```
ALTER TABLE `cust` ADD `custId` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Will the existing records be given auto incremented numbers at random, or can you give an order?

Comment: To give an order you have to add new field, i.e. `custId`, populate it with data and firstly then make this field as primary key and add AUTO_INCREMENT option.

Comment: 00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name" ERROR is showing now

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?